# Whoops to catch PDO errors?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, whoops

I use [whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) on my site, and now I try to get it work with PDO errors, it work fine when there missing a information to connect to the database, but when you (as a example) type a not existing table, it don't show a error.

I have try to add `PrettyPageHandler::addDataTable()` to my error handel

db.php

```
class db {

    // just some not important code here...

    // Try to get the result from database.
    try {
        $pdo = DB::getInstance()->db->prepare($sql);
        $pdo->execute($execute);
        $result = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // Return Result
        return $result;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        PrettyPageHandler::addDataTable(null, $e);
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
if(file_exists("plugins/whoops/autoload.php"))
{
    require_once 'plugins/whoops/autoload.php';
    $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
    $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler);
    $whoops->register();
}

require_once db.php';

$db = new db();
```

but then I get a *Class 'PrettyPageHandler' not found*

Comment: did you include/require the file that contains the PrettyPageHandler class?

Comment: Do you have `use Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler;` in your code?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil 2 sec I update the post

Comment: @flynorc just updated the post ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *full class name* or `use` statement. Change `PrettyPageHandler::addDataTable(null, $e);` to `\Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler::addDataTable(null, $e);`.

Comment: Non-static method Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler::addDataTable() should not be called statically

Comment: I looked at the Whoops documentation and it seems you should rather call `$whoops->handleException($e);` in the catch block.

Comment: Undefined variable: whoops

Comment: That could mean one of two things: 1) the code in your post is different from what you are actually trying to run 2) the `if(file_exists...` block does not get executed.

Comment: If `db.php` is included into `index.php`, the variable `$whoops` should be defined in the scope of `db.php`. What happens when you remove the `if(file_exists...` condition from index.php? (So that only lines starting with `require_once` or `$whoops` are left.)